# Call to a member function guessExtension() on string

Tags: symfony, symfony4

In Symfony 4 I'm getting this error:
Call to a member function guessExtension() on string
In previous I used same code to upload image and doing well, but here i'm getting error.
Has anyone faced the same issue and solved?

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $imageEn = new Image();

     $form = $this->createForm(ImageUploadType::class, $imageEn);

     $form->handleRequest($request);

     if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){


     /** @var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file */

        $file = $imageEn->getImage();

        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

        $file->move($this->getParameter('image_directory'), $fileName);

        $imageEn->setImage($fileName);
        $em->persist($imageEn);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('notice', 'Post Submitted Successfully!!!');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('image_upload');
     }
```

Form:

```
  {
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class)
        ->add('description', TextType::class)
        ->add('image', FileType::class, array('label'=>'Upload Image'))
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
    ;
}
```

Image Class:

Actually I followed a tutorial where he made this class manually but I used Command to create class, I tallied all his code with mine and it was correct.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ImageRepository")
*/
class Image
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please upload image")
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={"image/jpeg"})
 */
private $image;

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getTitle(): ?string
{
    return $this->title;
}

public function setTitle(string $title): self
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

public function getDescription(): ?string
{
    return $this->description;
}

public function setDescription(string $description): self
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

public function getImage(): ?string
{
    return $this->image;
}

public function setImage(string $image): self
{
    $this->image = $image;

    return $this;
}
```

}

Comment: What do you have in your `$request` object ? Do you see a file in it ?

Comment: No it's just public function indexAction(Request $request){}

Comment: No I mean, when you `dump($request->files)`, do you see the file that you expect in it ? Secondly, what your `Image` class is supposed to return when you call the method `getImage()` (an object, a string ?)

Comment: It's showing c/xampp/tmp/php3773.tmp

Comment: All right, so you correctly post a file but your `Image` object returns a string when you call `getImage()`. Can you show us you method `createForm()` please ?

Comment: I have updated the question please check

Comment: yes like this public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)

Comment: Yeap sorry I've wrote to quickly, I've removed my comment but it was too late...

Comment: Nope its ok... I'm just a learner, self taught Symfony dev..

Comment: I can't see what is wrong here. Can you please show your Image class or at least the `getImage` method ? Have you tried to `dump($imageEn->getImage());` to see what string it is ?

Comment: Here it is 
    public function getImage(): ?string
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

Comment: When I tried to dump() I got this one "C:\xampp\tmp\php2479.tmp"

Comment: Ok, can you show your full `Image` class please ? It will be easier to understand your problem. You can add it to the initial question to have all the informations in one place.

Comment: Hi, Ugo please check the class..

Comment: Sorry, I'm stuck too... :/ I don't understand why your image attribute is  hydrated with a string instead of a file object.

Comment: Is this a new kind of issue??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace

`$file = $imageEn->getImage()`

with

```
$file = $form->get('image')->getData();
```

Comment: i have the same problem.i'm using html form and not symfony's form !!

Comment: No problem use this code: $file = $request->files->get('name_file'); Don't forget form : <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Answer (score 4):

For me it was the typehinting of the entity that messed things up:

```
// I had to change this:
public function getImage(): ?string {}
public function setImage(string $image): self {}

// To this (both without 'string'):
public function getImage() {}
public function setImage( $image): self {}
```