# symfony 4 error when uploading file

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file, very much following the instructions on [Symfony's cookbook](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html), but it doesn't seem to work.

The specific error is as follows, but the background reason is that the file as such does not seem to be ( or remain ) uploaded.

> Call to a member function guessExtension() on string

As it happens, the file is momentarily created at upload_tmp_dir, but gets deleted almost immediately ( I know that 'cause I kept that directory visible on my Finder).

The file metadata is available on the var_dump($_FILES) command on the script below.

So, for some reason the file is being discarded which, I believe, causes the specific error seen above.

I believe $file ( from UploadedFile ), should receive the file as such, not the path to it, but not sure how to get there. Particularly is the file does not remain on upload_tmp_dir.

For information, I tried the upload in a plain PHP project I have and it works fine. The file remains in upload_tmp_dir till is moved elsewhere.

Thanks

Here is the controller:

```
class ApiUserXtraController extends Controller
{
public function UserXtraAction(Request $request, ValidatorInterface $validator) {

    $is_logged = $this->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');
    if ($is_logged) {
        $user = $this->getUser();
    }
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repo = $em->getRepository(UserXtra::class);

    $userxtra = new UserXtra();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($userxtra)
        ->add('imgFile', FileType::class, array('label' => 'file'))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Task'))
        ->getForm();

    var_dump($_FILES); // outputs file metadata, ie, name, type, tmp_name, size

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $userxtra->setUser($user);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 
        /** 
         * @var UploadedFile $file 
         * */
        $file = $userxtra->getImgFile();
        var_dump('file', $file);// outputs full path to upload_tmp_dir

        $fileName = $this->generateUniqueFileName().'.'.$file->guessExtension(); // **THIS THROWS THE ERROR**

        $file->move(
            $this->getParameter('user_image_directory'),
            $fileName
        );

        $userxtra->setImgFile($fileName);
        //$data = json_decode($data);
        return new JsonResponse(array(
            'status' => 'ok', 
            'is_logged' => $is_logged,
        ));
    }

    return $this->render('upload.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));

}
```

Comment: You noted in the code comment that getImageFile() `outputs full path to upload_tmp_dir`. That is a string not an object. You surely cannot use `->` notation on a variable of type string. guessExtension() is an instance method of UploadedFile.

Comment: I realize that, but that's exactly the code that you will find in Symfony's cookbook above. I am assuming it normally would get the file object, if the file was there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like

```
$form->getData('imgFile')->guessExtension();
```

instead?

Edit: Ah sorry, missed that you are assuming that `$file = $userxtra->getImgFile();` actually gives back an UploadedFile object. Apparently that assumption is not correct, as the error you are seeing indicates that it gives back a string instead.

Comment: Thanks, but the guessExtension() is a method of the UploadedFile class, not the $form class.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49604601/call-to-a-member-function-guessextension-on-string).

The docs, or actually Symfony's cookbook, is wrong.

The line on my code above that states:

> $file = $userxtra->getImgFile();

should be:

> $file = $form->get('imgFile')->getData();